# How to Autowire a Service in a regular java bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, autowired

I have a Spring project that I implemented a function to Audit when the Login is successful. The function works, but I need to write in the database when the Login is successful. My bean is:

> CustomLoginSucessHandler.java

```
 public class CustomLoginSucessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomLoginSucessHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws ServletException, IOException {       
            final String userName = authentication.getName();
            log.debug("User name is: " + userName);
            final User user = userService.getUser(userName);

            final Date date = new Date();
            final Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

            user.setLastLogin(timeStamp);

            userService.saveUser(user);
            log.debug("User Last Login update to " + timeStamp);

        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);

    }

}
```

Note that I have the `@Autowired` annotation but it always returns as `null`.

I already tried to annotate with `@Service` and `@Configurable`, no success so far.

> Stack Trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.opessoftware.fatca.web.util.CustomLoginSucessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(CustomLoginSucessHandler.java:33)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:245)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

Edit:

How I use my `CustomLoginSucessHandler`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Import({ DatabaseConfiguration.class })
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login.html")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll().and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll().and().exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/403.html");

            http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new CsrfRequestMatcher());     
            http.formLogin().successHandler(new CustomLoginSucessHandler());

        }
```

....

Comment: `CustomLoginSucessHandler` is not being managed by Spring, thus `@Autowired` won't work. Show how you're creating and using instances of `CustomLoginSucessHandler`

Comment: is the `UserService` bean correctly defined in your spring configuration file?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I edited the question

Comment: @mixmastered Yes it is, I can use UserService in other beans.

Comment: You need to have context.xml, where you need to add `<context:annotation-config />` and then `@Autowired` and `@PostConstruct` will be searched

Answer (score 0):

To get your beans in other context apart of your controllers you should use the next annotation:

```
<!--AUTOWIRED // THIS MAYBE YOU ALREADY HAVE-->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.system.rest.natura.controller" />
<!--ADD THIS ONE-->
    <context:annotation-config/>
```

if you have one or more spring.xml configure archive import them.

```
<import resource="/spring-config.xml" />
```

and also your CustomLoginSucessHandler should have the annotation:

```
@Component
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the solution here.

First of all I needed to create a class called `AuditingConfiguration.java`

And do this:

```
@Configuration
public class AuditingConfiguration {

    @Bean   
    public CustomLoginSucessHandler customLoginSucessHandler(){
        return new CustomLoginSucessHandler();
    }

}
```

After it, inside mine `SecurityConfiguration` I did this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Import({ DatabaseConfiguration.class, AuditingConfiguration.class })

public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private CustomLoginSucessHandler customLoginSucessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll().and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll().and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/403.html");

        http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new CsrfRequestMatcher());     
        http.formLogin().successHandler(customLoginSucessHandler);

    }
```

And now it works.